# Unable to download the change history and the discussion details of "Scrum tasks" in VSTS using odata

Tags: azure-devops, history, scrum

I don't exactly know how to fetch the change history and discussion details in VSTS. I have looked into Workitems and Work Item Revisions but didn't get any data related to history or discussion from it.

PFB the format of odata url used -

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}//WorkItemRevisions?
  $filter=WorkItemId eq {Id}
  &$select=WorkItemId, Title, State

https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}//WorkItems?
  $filter=WorkItemId eq {Id}
  &$select=WorkItemId, Title, State
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test we can only get the **change history** using the odata, but **cannot get discussion history**:

For example:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v1.0/WorkItemRevisions?$filter=WorkItemId eq 109&$select=WorkItemId, Title, State,Revision,RevisedDate,Reason,StateChangeDate

{
    "@odata.context": "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v1.0/$metadata#WorkItemRevisions(WorkItemId,Title,State,Revision,RevisedDate,Reason,StateChangeDate)",
    "value": [
        {
            "WorkItemId": 109,
            "Title": "0329Task2",
            "State": "To Do",
            "Revision": 7,
            "RevisedDate": "2018-07-09T14:02:01.473Z",
            "Reason": "New task",
            "StateChangeDate": "2018-03-29T02:29:36.91Z"
        }, 
       ...
       ...
       ...
       ...
```

To get the Discussion history you can use the REST API ([Revisions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/vsts/wit/revisions/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1)):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?api-version=4.1
```

Or [Get a list of all discussion history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/wit/history?view=tfs-2018):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/workItems/109/history
```